# set vs. vector of structs with string member

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl, set

For the following definitions:

```
struct Operand
    {
        Operand(std::string opName,bool isInput,bool isOutput,bool isReg) : m_opName(opName),m_isInput(isInput),m_isOutput(isOutput),m_isReg(isReg) {}
        std::string m_opName;
        bool m_isInput;
        bool m_isOutput;
        bool m_isReg;
    };
typedef std::set<Operand> SensitivityList;
SensitivityList m_sensitivityList;
```

The following loop should be executed:

```
for (SensitivityList::iterator it = m_sensitivityList.begin();it != m_sensitivityList.end();++it)
    {
        AddToInterfaceList(it->m_opName,portList,portList,false);
}
```

The signature of `AddToInterfaceList`is :

```
static void AddToInterfaceList(std::string& data,std::string& interfaceList32Bit,std::string& interfaceList1Bit);
```

The above code`s compilation fails with the error:

```
'AddToInterfaceList' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &'
```

If I redefine `SensitivityList`to be:

```
typedef std::vector<Operand> SensitivityList;
```

compilation succeeds.What is the problem with set vs. vector?
And how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Members of `set` are `const`. To fix, use `const std::string&` as your function arguments (everywhere; this is what you want to do anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators on std::set can only return const references to items in the set. If you could get a non-const reference to an item the set you could change the value of the item which could make the set no longer a proper set. If you change the first parameter of AddToInterfaceList to const std::string& data it should compile just fine.